# Error with MysqlDB python3 CentOS and _mysql Flask

Tags: python, mysql, mysql-python

I am trying to get my python3 flask app to work on Centos. At first I was getting this error:

`ImportError: this is MySQLdb version (1, 3, 10, 'final', 0), but _mysql is version (1, 2, 5, 'final', 1)`

So I removed python-mysql (whatever it was named) and Now I am not sure what to install to get this working.